# Derivation of Maxwell distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Short and basic/stupid question for today. I was having a second look at the derivation of the Maxwell distribution at temperature T from the definition of entropy in statistical physics.
I understand what I think is the "classic" derivation, with a system of energy Ei in thermal equilibrium with a heat bath of energy $E\gg E_i$.
However, I tried to see if I could take a shortcut, and end up with a dramatically wrong answer. Shamefully enough, I don't really see what's wrong with my stuff. Could you please point the error out? Thanks a bunch :)

Let's assume we have a system at temperature $T$ (could be the heat bath itself, or whatever system in thermal equilibrium at $T$)
The statistical entropy is defined as:
$$S=k_B\ln(\Omega),$$
where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates of the system at energy $E$. I am interested in the probability of having such an energy E. From the thermodynamic definition of temperature:
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}=T \Rightarrow \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}=1/T$$
therefore, for our system at temperature $T$:
$$\frac{1}{T}=k_B\frac{\partial }{\partial E}(\ln(\Omega))$$

$$\frac{1}{T}=k_b\frac{\partial \Omega }{\partial E}\frac{1}{\Omega}$$

$$\frac{\partial \Omega }{\partial E}=\frac{\Omega }{k_BT}$$

$$\Omega=e^{E/(k_bT)}+\text{cst}$$

The constant is zero. This is the number of microstates that have energy E. The probability of having energy E is therefore the ratio of this number of microstates to all possible microstates over all energy levels. This leads to a probability of having energy E of:
$$P_E=\frac{e^{E/(k_bT)}}{\sum_i{e^{E_i/(k_bT)}}}$$

When of course we should have $P_E=\frac{e^{-E/(k_bT)}}{\sum{e^{-E_i/(k_bT)}}}$.
Where the sum is over all quantum energy levels
What is wrong with this naive approach?

Comment: The problem is that $S=k_B\ln \Omega$ is valid for an isolated system and the Maxwell distribution that you are trying to derive is valid for a system in contact with a reservoir at a fixed temperature. In the standard derivation you derive the energy distribution of the system, whilst considering the number of microstates of the system *plus the environment*

Comment: Maybe the OP is just confused as from where the minus sign comes from?

Answer (score 0):

$\Omega$ is the number of microstates of the system at energy $E$. Thus, the probability of being in one of these microstates is proportional to $\frac{1}{\Omega}\sim e^{-E/k_BT}$. This leads to the probability of being in the microstate $i$:
\begin{equation}P_i=\frac{e^{-E_i/k_B T}}{\sum_j e^{-E_j/k_BT}}.\end{equation}
If we want to calculate the probability of having energy $E$, instead of the probability of being in the microstate $i$, the appropriate multiplicity has to be multiplied to the above equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate on the last part? I am now getting confused as to what exactly is governed by a Maxwell distribution... I am indeed interested in the probability of having energy E, as it was my understanding of the information I get from the distribution. I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: For instance, if there are four distinct states with energy E, the probability of having energy $E$ is given by $P_E=4e^{-E/k_BT}/Z$ where $Z$ is the partition function. Here, $Z$ would include four terms of $e^{-E/k_BT}$.

Comment: I might be reading you too litterally but what you describe equals one (if all the terms in your partition function have the same energy E, which you seem to imply)

Comment: If all states available have the energy $E$, then the probability of having energy $E$ must equal to 1, and there's no contradiction here. Otherwise, multiplying the multiplicity of the state will give $P_E$ as described above. Note that $\Omega e^{-E/k_BT}$ isn't exactly one due to constant factors. Generally, the partition function is calculated by summing over all states: $Z=\sum_i e^{-E_i/k_BT}$. If we want to write the partition function as a sum over energy, we have to apply the multiplicity in each term: $Z=\sum_E n_E e^{-E/k_BT}$ where $n_E$ is the number of states with energy $E$.

Comment: The distribution derived here is the Boltzmann distribution, and it should not be confused with the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. The Boltzmann distribution gives the probability that a system will be in a certain state as a function of that state's energy, while the Maxwell-Boltzmann distributions give the probabilities of particle speeds in ideal gases.

Comment: @User198:  The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution *is* the Boltzmann distribution as applied to ideal gases, though.